# Implementing "Sans Forgetica Regular" font in my webpage

Tags: html, css, webfonts

I've tried to setup "Sans Forgetica Regular" font to be the used font for entire a webpage after installing the font on my desktop of cource, however, it didn't work!
Does there a way to make it work please?

```
<body style="font-family:'Sans Forgetica Regular'">Hello</body>
```

Or

```
<body style="font-family:'SansForgetica-Regular'">Hello</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You declare it in the CSS like this:

```
@font-face {font-family: Sans Forgetica Regular; src: url('Sans-Forgetica-Regular.otf'); }
```

Then try it:

```
<body style="font-family:'Sans Forgetica Regular'">Hello</body>
```

Comment: Sorry @Rajesh I'm not able to give you +1, your code worked, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the [@font-face](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@font-face) rule:

> In this example, the user's local copy of "Sans Forgetica Regular" is
>   used; if the user does not have that font installed (two different
>   names are tried), then the downloadable font named
>   "SansForgetica-Regular.woff" is used instead:

**CSS**

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Sans Forgetica Regular';
  src: local('Sans Forgetica Regular'),
       local('Sans-Forgetica-Regular'),
       url('SansForgetica-Regular.woff') format('woff');
}

body {
  font-family: 'Sans Forgetica Regular';
}
```

**HTML** (Avoid using inline style)

```
<body>
  ...
</body>
```

Comment: Sorry @Armel I'm not able to give you +1, your code worked, thank you!

Comment: @e.b_al-issa you should be able to check the answer as valid no?

Comment: I’m not able to do so since my points still under 15 points as I think